# is it possible to add expander control in navigation bar in uwp?

Tags: uwp-xaml, navigationbar

i want to add Expander control to the navigation bar in my uwp application.

[image: this is the navigation bar i am having]

i want to add expander control in navigation view like this

[image: this is the navigation bar i am having]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you could custom `NavigationViewItem` style and set both height of `LayoutRoot` and `ContentGrid` as `auto` like the follow.

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationViewItemStyle1" TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="auto" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PointerStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelected}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelected}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Opacity" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IconStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="IconVisible"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IconCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="IconBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="IconColumn.Width" Value="16"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionIndicator" Fill="{ThemeResource NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground}" Height="24" Opacity="0.0" Width="6"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="RevealBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="IconColumn" Width="48"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip x:Name="ToolTip"/>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Viewbox x:Name="IconBox" Child="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Margin="16,12"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then custom `NavigationViewItem` ContentTemplate and add [**Microsoft Toolkit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/) [`Expander`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/expander)control in it.

```
<NavigationViewItem Style="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemStyle1}" Content="placeholder" >
 <NavigationViewItem.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="auto">
                <controls:Expander x:Name="Expander2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" 
                           Background="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}"
                           Header="This is the header"       
                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                           IsExpanded="False"
                           ExpandDirection="Down">
                    <Grid Height="auto"
                       Background="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}">
                        <ListView>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <x:String>Item1</x:String>
                            <x:String>Item2</x:String>
                            <x:String>Item3</x:String>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </controls:Expander>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationViewItem.ContentTemplate>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your support,and i want to know it is possible to change the list view arrow position from left to right?

Comment: For custom expander please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/expander#headerstyle)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using Microsoft toolkit controls. You have an expander control in that toolkit that supports UWP.

Install Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls from Nuget packages.

Define toolkit in your XAML header as below and use it in design as below code.

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

<controls:Expander Header="Header" Background="White">
        <controls:Expander.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White">
                    <Button Foreground="Black" Background="White" Padding="0">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="credentials"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Expander.HeaderTemplate>
            <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Expanded content" />
        </Grid>
    </controls:Expander>
```

This will be output of the above code.

[image: Before expand]

[image: After expand]

You can modify it based on your requirement.

[Follow this link for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/expander)